How can I put multiple case classes in to single RDD(and then DataSet)
From one single full raw data, I have to extract some data and dump multiple type of data.
I need to dump multiple format of data in different path.
In Simple Example
case class A (id: Int, age: Int, name: String)

case class B (id: Int, age: Int, married: Boolean)

case class C (id: Int, age: Int, gender: String)

A dump to hdfs://some/a
B dump to hdfs://some/b
C dump to hdfs://some/c
Dumping it sequentially might be naive solution.
But since those case classes have multiple common fields, I think it is quite inefficient.
What I though was making some parent trait or abstract class and extends it.
And then add category field in case class.
Finally making it one RDD[P]->DataSet[P] use partitionBy(category) to dump in different path.
In example
trait P(category: String, id: Int, age: Int)

case class A (category: String, id: Int, age: Int, name: String)

case class B (category: String, id: Int, age: Int, married: Boolean)

case class C (category: String, id: Int, age: Int, gender: String)


On my IDE, it looks like making RDD[P] works, but transforming it in to DataSet(through .toDS() method) did not work.
Is there any way to solve it?
(Not making class with complex methods like compare or etc...)
Edition
I totally want the dump format to be different, since dump will be on different path.
In example
case class A dump format



id
age
name




1
20
Joe



case class B dump format



id
age
married




1
20
false



Below is not intended dump format



id
age
name
married




1
20
Joe
None


2
24
None
True




Does this answer your question? Scala DataSet with case class inheritance, also see this one that's a follow up.

@Chris Thanks for your suggestion. It helped a lot, but what I need is to remove null fields. (Actually who reads these data want it)

per the link I gave you you can use the null fields to decide which concrete instance it is.
